# Regex - separate multiple words and whitespace from decimal numbers at the end

Tags: r, regex

I have a string containing words, whitespace and numbers (integers and decimals). I want to separate them into two columns in a data frame so that column `A` contains the text and column `B` contains the number. It seems like a super simple task but I cannot figure out how to capture the text. I did capture the numbers though.

```
require(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c("This is text0", "This is a bit more text 0.01", "Even more text12.231"))
```

Captured the number in column `B` but I cannot figure out how what regex to put in the first set of parentheses to get the text in `A`:

```
df |> 
  extract(x, c("A", "B"), "()(\\d+\\.*\\d*)")
#  A      B
#1        0
#2     0.01
#3   12.231
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
extract(x, c("A", "B"), "^(.*?)\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Ihk02/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: That's great! Could you please help me understand when to use a non capturing group in a capturing group (see Group 2)? Newb here :) THX!

Comment: @Stefan It is not a must or anything too sophisticated. Just use a non-capturing group when you need to modify matching behavior of a whole sequence of patterns. Here, `.` and one or more digits must match one or zero times, hence the `\.` + `\d+` are grouped.

Answer (score 2):

We capture one or more letters/space (`([A-Za-z ]+)`) followed by any space and the digits with . (`[0-9.]+`)

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, x, into = c("A", "B"), "([A-Za-z ]+)\\s*([0-9.]+)", convert = TRUE)
                         A      B
1             This is text  0.000
2 This is a bit more text   0.010
3           Even more text 12.231
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted Wiktor's answer as it seems more versatile and also got rid of the extra whitespace in the 2nd row at the end of the string, which is nice. Yet your regex is easier to understand for me.

Answer (score 2):

With {unglue} you might do :

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c("This is text0", "This is a bit more text 0.01", "Even more text12.231"))
unglue::unglue_unnest(df, x, "{A}{B=[0-9.]+}")
#>                          A      B
#> 1             This is text      0
#> 2 This is a bit more text    0.01
#> 3           Even more text 12.231
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>